# Typiclal DNS lookup behaviour of browsers on diffent platforms, for IP addresses?

Tags: operating-system, browser, dns

When browsers look up hostnames, do they do that even when the "host name" is an IP address? For instance http://74.125.39.105/ goes to some Google servers. Will this result in a DNS lookup on common browsers and platforms, such as Safari, IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Windows, Linux, Mac OSX?

Or will the browser (in the common case) just start a connection directly without trying a DNS lookup first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no DNS lookup done if the entire host part is numeric in nature.  It could be in dotted quad format, or a single unsigned 32 bit integer.  I haven't tested IPv6 yet.

Comment: Single unsigned 32 bit integer?  What does such an address look like?

Comment: eg, if your IP is 10.0.0.1, then just write the bits of each number side by side, and you get the 32 bit number, so you basically have:

00001010.00000000.00000000.00000001
which is 
00001010000000000000000000000001
which, in decimal is 335544320 (if I've done my math right)

Comment: No, it's 167772161 :) 74.125.39.105 becomes 1249716073 (so in some browsers you can visit http://1249716073/ and it'll take you to Google).

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in performing a lookup as there are no authoritative DNS records for these numeric "names".

Some recursive nameservers (e.g. [dnscache](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/dnscache.html)) will respond to these kind of queries with the corresponding IP address, as if there was a real record of the form:

```
74.125.39.105. IN A 74.125.39.105
```

but this is, I assume, intended to deal with simplistic clients that assume everything is a DNS name. The most common nameserver, BIND, doesn't have this behaviour though - so don't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks!  I had an idea some resolvers would answer, but also wanted to know how common it is to actually ask the DNS query for IP addresses.